Infinite Integration Issues
Let me preface this by saying that I know I'm doing something wrong, I'm just here to find out what exactly.
We know that integrating a function yields constants. Something like $e^x$ yields $+c$ when integrated. It doesn't matter what arbitrary value of $c$ we choose, because when differentiated, it just goes away. When integrated multiple times, we get more constants, and powers of $x$ start popping out as well. So, if we integrate $e^x$ 3 times, we would get something like $e^x+c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3$, which, regardless of the constants, when differentiated 3 times would yield $e^x$ again. Said differently, we can say that the $(n+1)$-th integral of $e^x$ is equal to:
$$e^x + \sum_{0}^{n}a(n)*x^{n}$$
As $n$ goes to infinity (we integrate $e^x$ infinitely many times), we get an infinite power series. My issue with this is that power series can represent functions. So, if we say for example that our infinite power series has constants such that $a(n) = \frac{1}{n!}$, as we go out to infinity, this power series represents a function ($e^x$). Ok, so if we integrate $e^x$ infinitely many times, we get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^x+\sum_{0}^{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
where the power series is equal to $e^x$. Making this substitution yields $e^x + e^x$, which is just $2e^x$. Ok, so infinitely integrating $e^x$ yields $2e^x$. Obviously wrong. Moreover, it doesn't matter how many times I differentiate $2e^x$, I can do it infinitely many times, and I'm still never getting back to $e^x$. So where is the mistake? Integration yields constants. I am allowed to choose the value of my constants (because they don't matter if I differentiate them away). However, if I choose constants such that as I integrate out to infinity, the constants times the powers of $x$ create the power series of a function, I feel it ought to be legal to simply substitute in that function. But then, no amount of differentiation will yield the original function. So, what gives? I feel like it has something to do with the fact that I can't just choose my own constants, but I'm arguing that it doesn't matter, because $n$ integrations should come undone by $n$ differentiations, regardless of my constants.

An example: defining $J(f)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}J^{\circ n}(\exp)(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Simply put,
$$
{e}^{x} \neq \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac {{x}^{k}}{k!}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb {N}$, so
$$
\frac {\text {d}^{n}}{{\left( \text {d} x \right)}^{n}} {e}^{x} = {e}^{x} \neq 1 = \frac {\text {d}^{n}}{{\left( \text {d} x \right)}^{n}} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac {{x}^{k}}{k!},
$$
in general.

The mistake is that even when one has a pattern that works for every positive integer $n$, one can't simply change $n$ to $\infty$ and assume that the statements work the same way. There is no such thing as "integrating/differentiating infinitely many times". One can take a sequence of functions obtained by $n$-fold integration/differentiation, and then (sometimes) take the limit of that sequence of functions; but the resulting limit might have nothing to do with integrating/differentiating the original function.

It is to be recalled from the fundamental theorem of calculus that the choice of the integration constant is equivalent to the choice of a specific primitive by setting an initial/boundary condition. Indeed, the relations $\int f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = F(x) + c$ and $\int_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = F(x) - F(a)$ implies $F(a) = -c$. In the reverse perspective, $F(x)$ is the solution to the differential equation $y'(x) = f(x)$ together with the initial condition $y(a) = c$.
One can apply this process $n$-times successively, in such a way that $y_n(x) = f^{(-n)}(x) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$, where $f^{(-n)}(x)$ is a $n^\mathrm{th}$ primitive of a function $f(x)$, is the solution to the problem $y^{(n)}(x) = f(x)$ with the initial conditions $y^{(k)}(a_k) = 
c_k \;\forall k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. In your case, one has $f(x) = F(x) = e^x$ and $c_k = 1 \;\forall k$. It is to be noted that the polynomial part corresponds to the homogeneous solution, hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \frac{x^k}{k!} = 0
\tag{$*$}
$$
Now, your paradox arises in the limit $n \to \infty$, because you treated separately the problem of integrating the function $f(x)$ and the "parallel" problem of solving the differential equation $y^{(n)}(x)$. Consequently, you considered two different limit process and you discovered they don't commute, i.e.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\lim_{m\to\infty} y_m^{(n)}(x)\right) \neq \lim_{m\to\infty} \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} y_m^{(n)}(x)\right),
$$
because the condition $(*)$ is not satisfied anymore when $n \le m$ $-$ in other words, the series $\sum_{k=0}^m c_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$ don't belong to the kernel of the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative. And that is why you weren't able to recover the initial exponential by differentiating the expression back (i.e. when you tried to verify that it constitutes a valid solution to the implicit differential equation).

You are considering a sequence of functions defined as follows: Start with $f_0(x) = e^x$ and then successively take anti-derivatives like so:
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) & = e^x + 1 \\
f_2(x) & = e^x + 1 + x \\
f_3(x) & = e^x + 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2 \\
\vdots &  \\
f_n(x) & = e^x + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}x^k
\end{align*}
You've observed that the sequence $\{f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), \ldots\}$ has a limit, namely
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = e^x + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}x^k = 2e^x.$$
You've also observed that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\right] = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(2e^x) = 2e^x$$
is not equal to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f_n(x)\right] = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_0(x) = e^x$$
and are asking what went wrong.  In fact, nothing went wrong.  The point is that for a sequence of infinitely differentiable functions $\{g_1(x), g_2(x), \ldots\}$ that approaches a limit function $G(x)$,
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) \ \ \ \text{need not equal} \ \ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} g_n(x).$$
So, even though $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f_n(x) = e^x$ is true, it is nevertheless also true that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[ \lim f_n(x) ] = 2e^x$.  There is no contradiction here.

This is a beautiful example of what can go wrong when you interchange two limits. On one side you have
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{d^m}{dx^m} \left( e^x+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\tfrac{x^k}{k!}\right)
=\lim_{m\to\infty} \tfrac{d^m}{dx^m}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( e^x+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\tfrac{x^k}{k!}\right)=2e^x
$$
On the other side you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\tfrac{d^m}{dx^m} \left( e^x+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\tfrac{x^k}{k!}\right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( e^x+0\right)=e^x
$$
In the first displayed equation you have to justify taking the derivatives $d^m/dx^m$  outside the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$. In this case that can be done.
